# How to merge multiple images in to single image ( like Multiple exposure feature in DSLR Cameras ) in SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimage, avfoundation

I'm developing the PhotoEditing app. I want to merge multiple images. Captured the array of images using AVFoundation framework. Now i want to merge these images. I tried with this method, but It's not working the way i want, it is just appending images one by one.

```
let bottomImage = images[0]
let frontImage = images[1]
let size = CGSize(width: 67, height: 55)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
let frontImageSize = CGRect(x: 14, y: 3, width: 40, height: 40)
bottomImage.draw(in: areaSize, blendMode: CGBlendMode.normal, alpha:  1.0)
frontImage.draw(in: frontImageSize, blendMode: CGBlendMode.normal, alpha: 1.0)
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

if let imageData = newImage?.pngData() {
    previewView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to see the background image through the front image(?) then you'll need to change the `alpha` on the `frontImage`. A value of 1 will make it completely opaque, a value 0f 0.5 will make it semi transparent

Comment: "Like multiple exposure feature"? So you want to do exposure bracketing? Focus stacking? Stitching images together into a panoramic image? There's at least half-a-dozen different ways you can combine images, all requiring very different (and complex) image processing. Be more specific.